# Why i cant display block on hover in css

Tags: css

so here the situation,i wanna make a header for html. and at first i want the header is hidden. and when i hover my mouse on the top of browser. the header display block.
here's the code

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">

        .atas{
            top:0px;
            background-color: #5F5F5F;
            width: 100%;
            height: 50px;
            position: fixed;
            right:0px;
            left:0px;
            visibility: hidden;
        }
        .menu{

            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
            height: 50px;
           background-color: red;
        }
        .menu:hover .atas{
           visibility: visible;
        }
      </style>  
</head>
<body >

    <div class="menu">Menu</div>
    <div class="atas">
        </div>

     </body>
```

why it didnt show the "atas" div when i hover the "menu" div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution to the blinking divs problem described in the comments of Gauravs answer.
Also set the :hover state of the .atas div to block.

```
.menu:hover + .atas, .atas:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

Here is the corresponding fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lr67ht6r/2/

Answer (score 2):

The way you have written the css will work if `.atas` is child div of `.menu` but its not. Its a sibling so you need to write like this

```
.menu:hover + .atas{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

> Here `+` specifies the next sibling

Comment: ahh i see! thanks.but there's next problem when i hover the menu div.when i move the cursor it just like visible > hidden > visible.is there any other way to do better?

Comment: try using `display:none` and `display:block`

Comment: its still the same.when i move the cursor,but still in the area of menu div.it will display > none > display.what i want is when i hover the menu area the "atas" div will show once.when i mouse out it will hide.do i have to use javascript?

Comment: not at all..there might be spaces between the menu inner elements because till the time you hovered menu if will remain `display:block`

Comment: here's the fiddle if i didnt bother you to help me http://jsfiddle.net/uLCu5/121/

Comment: this is crazy...ok this is happening because when you hover your css works and `.atas ` shows but `.atas` is overlapped on `.menu` so when it shows you cursor comes on `.atas` so css changes to `display:none`. Got the point?

Comment: i got it.so is there any other way to do what i want?sorry for my limited knowledge

Comment: align `.atas` after the `.menu` or use javascript to add class

Comment: im sorry for ask.could you write the javascript code ? because i not yet learn much for javascript.

Comment: but with the javascript code you can add css on hover but on what event you want to remove that css